# Reduce CPU utilization in constant pinging to API and saving data in to database service

Tags: c#, performance, .net, asp.net-core

I have this hosted service which grabs the data from API every second and process the data and save it into the database.

I have similar 3 more hosted services which run at the same time. Because of this, the CPU utilization is always high, I'm sure because of the `foreach` loops in functions and service but without that it's hard to iterate data, can anyone help me optimize this code?

CPU utilization improved significantly after calling `GetBuilds()`

```
public class SandBoxService : DelegatingHandler, IHostedService
        {
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            private Timer _timer;
            public IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;
            protected HttpClient _client_SB;
            private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
            string connectionString = "";

            public SandBoxService(IConfiguration configuration, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
                _clientFactory = clientFactory;
                _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
                connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

                // NamedClients foreach Env.
                _client_SB = _clientFactory.CreateClient("SandBoxEnv");
            }

            public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                _timer = new Timer(GetAccessToken, null, 0, 3300000);
                _timer = new Timer(Heartbeat, null, 0, 1000);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                //Timer does not have a stop. 
                _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            public async Task<Token> GetToken(Uri authenticationUrl, Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials)
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(authenticationCredentials);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(authenticationUrl, content);

                if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string message = String.Format("POST failed. Received HTTP {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    throw new ApplicationException(message);
                }

                string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(responseString);

                return token;
            }

            private void GetAccessToken(object state)
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> authenticationCredentials_sb = Configuration.GetSection("SandBoxEnvironment:Credentials").GetChildren().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.Value)).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
                Token token_sb = GetToken(new Uri(Configuration["SandBoxEnvironment:URL"]), authenticationCredentials_sb).Result;

                _client_SB.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token_sb.AccessToken}");
            }

            public void Heartbeat(object state)
            {
                // Discard the result
                _ = GetOrg();
                _ = GetApps();
                _ = GetSpace();
                _ = GetBuilds();
            }

            public async Task GetOrg()
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "organizations");
                var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OrganizationsClass.OrgsRootObject>(json);

                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();

                    foreach (var item in model.resources)
                    {
                        var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
                        var x = _DBcontext.Organizations.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OrgGuid == g);
                        if (x == null)
                        {
                            _DBcontext.Organizations.Add(new Organizations
                            {
                                OrgGuid = g,
                                Name = item.name,
                                CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                                UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                                Timestamp = DateTime.Now,
                                Foundation = 2
                            });
                        }
                        else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                        {
                            x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                            x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                            x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }
                    await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }

            public async Task GetSpace()
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "spaces");
                var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                SpacesClass.SpaceRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpacesClass.SpaceRootObject>(json);

                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();

                    foreach (var item in model.resources)
                    {
                        var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
                        var x = _DBcontext.Spaces.FirstOrDefault(o => o.SpaceGuid == g);
                        if (x == null)
                        {
                            _DBcontext.Spaces.Add(new Spaces
                            {
                                SpaceGuid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                                Name = item.name,
                                CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                                UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                                OrgGuid = Guid.Parse(item.relationships.organization.data.guid),
                                Foundation = 2,
                                Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                            });
                        }

                        else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                        {
                            x.CreatedAt = item.created_at;
                            x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                            x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }
                    await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }

            public async Task GetApps()
            {
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps?per_page=200");
                var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                AppsClass.AppsRootobject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppsClass.AppsRootobject>(json);
                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();

                    foreach (var item in model.resources)
                    {
                        var g = Guid.Parse(item.guid);
                        var x = _DBcontext.Apps.FirstOrDefault(o => o.AppGuid == g);

                        if (x == null)
                        {
                            _DBcontext.Apps.Add(new Apps
                            {
                                AppGuid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                                Name = item.name,
                                State = item.state,
                                CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                                UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                                SpaceGuid = Guid.Parse(item.relationships.space.data.guid),
                                Foundation = 2,
                                Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                            });
                        }

                        else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                        {
                            x.State = item.state;
                            x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                            x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                        }
                    }

                    var guids = model.resources.Select(r => Guid.Parse(r.guid));
                    var apps = _DBcontext.Apps.Where(o => guids.Contains(o.AppGuid) == false && o.Foundation == 2 && o.DeletedAt == null);
                    foreach (var app in apps)
                    {
                        app.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    }


                    await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }

            public async Task GetBuilds()
            {
                var data = new List<GetBuildTempClass>();
                var guids = new List<Guid>();


                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        string commandText = @"SELECT 
                                                a.name as AppName,
                                                a.app_guid as AppGuid
                                            FROM
                                                apps as a
                                            INNER JOIN
                                                spaces as s ON a.space_guid = s.space_guid
                                            INNER JOIN
                                                organizations as o ON s.org_guid = o.org_guid
                                            WHERE s.name != 'system' and o.name != 'system' and a.foundation = 2 and a.deleted_at IS NULL";
                        try
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

                            await connection.OpenAsync();

                            using (DbDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                            {
                                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                                {
                                    var sqlresult = new GetBuildTempClass
                                    {
                                        AppName = reader["AppName"].ToString(),
                                        AppGuid = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("AppGuid"))
                                    };
                                    data.Add(sqlresult);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            connection.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
                using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
                {

                    var _DBcontext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PCFStatusContexts>();

                    foreach (var app in data)
                    {
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "apps/" + app.AppGuid + "/builds?per_page=200&order_by=updated_at");
                        var response = await _client_SB.SendAsync(request);
                        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildsClass.BuildsRootObject>(json);

                        foreach (var item in model.resources)
                        {
                            var x = _DBcontext.Builds.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Guid == Guid.Parse(item.guid));

                            if (x == null)
                            {
                                _DBcontext.Builds.Add(new Builds
                                {
                                    Guid = Guid.Parse(item.guid),
                                    State = item.state,
                                    CreatedAt = item.created_at,
                                    UpdatedAt = item.updated_at,
                                    Error = item.error,
                                    CreatedByGuid = Guid.Parse(item.created_by.guid),
                                    CreatedByName = item.created_by.name,
                                    CreatedByEmail = item.created_by.email,
                                    AppGuid = app.AppGuid,
                                    AppName = app.AppName,
                                    Foundation = 2,
                                    Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                                });
                            }

                            else if (x.UpdatedAt != item.updated_at)
                            {
                                x.State = item.state;
                                x.UpdatedAt = item.updated_at;
                                x.Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
                            }

                            guids.Add(Guid.Parse(item.guid));
                        }
                    }

                    var apps = _DBcontext.Builds.Where(o => guids.Contains(o.Guid) == false && o.Foundation == 2 && o.DeletedAt == null);
                    foreach (var app_item in apps)
                    {
                        app_item.DeletedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    }

                    await _DBcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: mhmm a lot of data requries a lot of processing. You should use a profiler first to identify which part of the code might requrie optimization. Since we cannot run it we cannot find it ourselfs.

Comment: @t3chb01 `GetBuilds()` using a lot of CPU and thus it needs optimization.

Comment: And how do you know that if you haven't profiled it yet?

Comment: If I don't call that function CPU utilization is normal.

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

- `GetBuilds` does multiple things, so split that up into smaller methods that each do a specific job. And then check which of those methods causes the issues.
- Use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) instead of ADO.NET. (Why are you even mixing ADO.NET and Entity Framework?)
- Are the DB properties you do `INNER JOIN`s on properly indexed?
- Don't add "Class" to the name of a class, nor "Object" to whatever `BuildsRootObject` is.
- Name things properly: "data is waaay too generic a name, and "x" is even worse. Don't pointlessly abbreviate, e.g. "Org" instead of "Organisation".
- Don't retrieve records one at a time in a loop (`var x = _DBcontext.Builds.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Guid == Guid.Parse(item.guid));`), instead get them all at once and store them in a dictionary and then use `TryGetValue` to check if a particular record exists.
- This whole class is approx. 300 lines. That is IMHO too long. A method like `GetBuilds()` should be its own class, with multiple methods doing specific jobs. Even simpler methods like `GetApps()` or `GetSpace()` or `GetOrg()` could be their own class.
- Why is the `guid` property of `OrgsRootObject` a `string` instead of a `Guid`?

Comment: Thank you so much I will look into it, about your question in second point I was not aware I'm mixing that two stuff I'm very new to C# and yet too learn all small pieces.

Comment: @Sam You are allowed to mix them, but I wonder why you even did it here. Entity framework can handle "raw sql" like the one you used, so why then use ADO.NET?

Comment: The main reason I used query like that is to use `async` in the entity you can not open connection and close the way I did in my code. Correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: @Sam Unless you're using an older version of EF, of course you can do async: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/async or https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/async-query-and-save.aspx etc.

Comment: ohhhh my bad then